# Where to find Netezza Sequence data?

Tags: sequence, netezza

Information about sequences can be found in the **_vt_sequence** view which can be joined with **_v_sequence** on _v_sequence.objid = _vt_sequence.seq_id.

sequence fetch query :

```
select vs.* , vts.*
from  _v_sequence vs join _vt_sequence vts on vs.objid = vts.seq_id;
```

Following values generated out of queries :

```
OBJID
SEQNAME
OWNER
CREATEDATE
OBJTYPE
OBJCLASS
OBJDELIM
DATABASE
OBJDB
SCHEMA
SCHEMAID
SEQ_ID
DB_ID
DATA_TYPE
MIN_VALUE
MAX_VALUE
CYCLE
INCREMENT
CACHE_SIZE
NEXT_CACHE_VAL
FLAGS
```

Sample CREATE SEQUNCE:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TEMP_PPC_SEQ AS BIGINT
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 2
NO MINVALUE
MAXVALUE 2147483647
NO CYCLE;
```

There is no value for **START**  of sequence. 
Help to fetch START value of each sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You can find start value in sequence table. Unfortunately netezza don't update last value in this table. Your answer is

```
SELECT s.LAST_VALUE
  FROM sequence1 s;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the "START WITH" value used by the DDL at creation time by selecting from the sequence object itself, as if it were a table, and referencing the LAST_VALUE column.

Don't be confused by the column name.  LAST_VALUE does not report the last value dispensed by the sequence.  The below example demonstrates this.

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> create sequence test_seq_1 as bigint start with 12345;
CREATE SEQUENCE

TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> create temp table seq_out as select next value for test_seq_1 from _v_vector_idx a cross join _v_vector_idx b;
INSERT 0 1048576

TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select * from test_seq_1;
 SEQUENCE_NAME | LAST_VALUE | INCREMENT_BY |      MAX_VALUE      | MIN_VALUE | CACHE_VALUE | LOG_CNT | IS_CYCLED | IS_CALLED | DATATYPE
---------------+------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+-----------+----------
 TEST_SEQ_1    |      12345 |            1 | 9223372036854775807 |         1 |      100000 |       1 | f         | f         |       20
(1 row)

TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select next value for test_seq_1;
 NEXTVAL
---------
 1060921
(1 row)
```

Comment: Using LAST_VALUE , will give last sequence generated out of sequence...I am looking for START WITH which is CREATE SEQUENCE DDL.

Comment: Hi My answer provides an example to the contrary. Laser value reports the  initial start value.